# Error during data binding: property is null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-databinding

I have a component list and its child (component item). 
I'm trying to pass information from list to item, but it seem data binding doesn't work because the object is null, even if i have (hope) correctly initialized.

This is the list component with its own template:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';
import { RecipeItemComponent } from './recipe-item.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
  styles: []
})

export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() recipeSelected = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();
  recipes: Recipe[] = [];
  public recipe: Recipe;

  constructor() {
    this.recipe = new Recipe('Dummy', 'Dummy', 'http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mfXELL6zPWJE4OC0agiXMZw.jpg');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelected(recipe: Recipe) {
    this.recipeSelected.emit(recipe);
  }
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <app-recipe-item> [recipe]="recipe" (click)="onSelected(recipe)"></app-recipe-item>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here the component item:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-item',
  templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe: Recipe;
  recipeId: number;

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

<a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{name}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{description}}</p>
  </div>
  <span class="pull-right">
      <img class="img-responsive"
           src="{{imagePath}}"
           style="max-height: 50px;"/>
  </span>
</a>
```

The error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./RecipeItemComponent class RecipeItemComponent - inline template:2:40 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
ViewWrappedError
Error: Error in ./RecipeItemComponent class RecipeItemComponent - inline template:2:40 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6880:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24986:16)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:25051:16)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:53759:16)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72648:23)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72621:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72408:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_RecipeListComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/RecipeListComponent/component.ngfactory.js:96:20)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72423:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72618:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72408:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_RecipesComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/RecipesComponent/component.ngfactory.js:83:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72423:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72618:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:72408:18)
```

Here is my angular version:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 7.6.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

Thanks for any suggest.

Added information:

Recipe class object:

```
export class Recipe {
    constructor(public name: string, public description: string, public imagePath: string) {

    }
}
```

Comment: `<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>` ?

Comment: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, check your variable declaration in  `RecipeItemComponent `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you don't actually bind to `recipe` in your template. You are attempting to bind to its properties by themselves. Try `{{recipe.name}}`, for example, instead of just `{{name}}`.

There is another error here:

```
<app-recipe-item> [recipe]="recipe" (click)="onSelected(recipe)"></app-recipe-item>
```

Notice the closed tag at the `app-recipe-item` selector. I don't know if that's present in your markup, or not. Fix this like this.

```
 <app-recipe-item [recipe]="recipe" (click)="onSelected(recipe)"></app-recipe-item>
```

Finally, can you explain why you'd emit `recipe` on clicking `app-recipe-item` when you already have `recipe` in the parent component? In other words, `app-recipe-item` appears to be getting `recipe` from the parent component. It's unclear why the parent component would need to get it back from the child.

Comment: Thanks so much, Your eyes are better than mine. The problem was the misformatted html as you noticed. Now it runs as expected. Thanks again!!

Comment: When it comes to your own code, everyone's eyes are better. (: Out of curiosity, I assume that you also needed to add `{{recipe.name}}` instead of just `{{name}}`. Is that correct? If not, I'll remove that from my answer. I'd also like to know why.

Comment: You are right. I left just for a try and i paste in my question. Everything is as it should be :)

Answer (score 0):

Try default initialization of:
@Input() recipe: Recipe = new Recipe() using a 'default' object inside the RecipeItemComponent or/and 
define the public recipe: Recipe inside the app-recipe-list with a default Recipe object.